# What is the last stage to attach viewstate Data to a dynamic control?

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

I have an `Ascx` control which I reload every `Page_load` using `Loadcontrol`.

This `Ascx` has a Button And Label

The Label *initially*  contains "`aaa`".

When I click the button the page *reloads* and *recreates* the ascx.

The good thing is that the `"aaa"` is kept - although it's a *new* instance of the ascx.

I was wondering to my self *why ?* and I've answered to myself that's its because the ID of the ASCX which is the same so he is attaching the viewstate from the last postback to the current instance.

**Question**

What is the *latest* page event which I can create the control 
*so that* it will be able to attach the viewstate (from the last postback)to the new generated control ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following are the events occur during **ASP.NET Page Life Cycle**:

```
1)Page_PreInit
2)Page_Init
3)Page_InitComplete
4)Page_PreLoad
5)Page_Load
6)Control Events
7)Page_LoadComplete
8)Page_PreRender
9)SaveViewState
10)Page_Render
11)Page_Unload
```

Among above events **Page_Render** is the only event which is raised by page. So we can't write code for this event.

Comment: Sikender , sorry for my latest comment :) -  i just saw you also answeerd me ...  :)     so for each of the events i can create the new control ? ( except pre-render...) ? is that correct ? what about page_init ? does the viewstate is available there ?  i dont think so , so how woul he make the match  and attach the latest viewstate?

Comment: Viewstate is available after the init and before the page load or on load for a control.

Comment: @shamim : my test in the page load also worked. he **did** attach the viewstate from the previouse postback...